# error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: file too short

Tags: centos6, glibc, steam

I'm running this on CentOS 6.8 (Final)
I'm trying to setup a Arma 3 Wasteland server for me and some friends.
But when I try to run it it gives the following error:

```
./arma3server: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./arma3server)
```

I'm not an advanced linux user, I'm more of a noob, I tried googling but it doesn't work, is there anyone that could help me fix this? Just give me a step by step guide of what I have to do please. If you need more info then please ask I'd be happy to give more information.

After trying to fix it I now get this error:
`./arma3server: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: file too short`

Comment: Exactly what do you do when you see this error? Are there more messages around?

Comment: I've found this: https://gyazo.com/1535b79723eb483bbc1384948a314b24
It's still searching so if it finds anything more I'll update it

Comment: ]$ ./arma3server -name=server -config=server.cfg
./arma3server: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./arma3server)